# How to generate ORM.XML mapping files from annotations?

Tags: orm, jpa, openjpa

At work, we design solutions for rather big entities in the financial services area, and we prefer to have our deployment mappings in XML, since it's easy to change without having to **recompile**.

We would like to do our development using annotations and generate from them the `orm.xml` mapping files. I found [this proof of concept annotation processor](http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/marx-jse6.html), and something like that is what I'm looking for, but something that has support for most JPA annotations.

We're using WebSphere for development so we would prefer something that considers the OpenJPA implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible approach:

1. use the annotated classes to generate the database schema
2. use OpenJPA's [`SchemaTool`](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_schema_schematool.html) to reverse engineer the database schema into their XML schema file
3. use OpenJPA's [`ReverseMappingTool`](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_pc_reverse.html) to generate XML mapping files from the XML schema file

Comment: It's still not perfect, however, because it duplicates my entities, since the tables are not named exactly the same as the entity class, plus it doesn't do it quite right. OpenJPA's tools seem rather sloppy

Comment: @Miguel I consider the above more as a hack than a perfect solution and I'm not surprised the result isn't perfect. For a perfect solution, I suggest to write the orm.xml manually :)